# Nested es6 array destructuring?

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to nest destructuring?

E.g. I want the first item in an array and in that array I want the first item of that child array.

Given:

```
let arr = [['foo'], ['bar']];
```

Is there an easier way to do:

```
let firstItem = arr[0][0];
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ah figured this out:

```
let [[firstItem]] = arr;
```

That would be the equivalent.

Comment: you can destructure nested objects the same way fyi ^_^

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible to destructure nested arrays (and objects).

Let's consider this nested array `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`, which is a 2D array. To get the 1st child-array's 1st element,

```
let [[x]] = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

To get the 2nd child-array's 1st element,

```
let [,[x]] = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Here, comma is used to skip elements. To get the 2nd element of the third child-array like this:

```
let [,,[,x]] = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If you want to retrieve a specific element as well as the remaining elements in an array, you can use the rest operator `...`. For example, to get the 3rd child-array's first element and the remaining elements separately,

```
let [,,[x, ...others]] = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]] // x=1, others=[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am just assuming multiple items just to make syntax more clear.

```
let arr = [['foo','foo1'], ['bar','bar1']];
var a,b,c,d;
[[a,b],[c,d]] = arr;
console.log(a,b,c,d); // foo,foo1,bar,bar1
```